# How can I create a table with conditionally editable input/cells using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, conditional-statements, react-state-management

I have a table like this:

[image]

When a user clicks on an `Edit` button, an `<input>` should appear in its place.

If a user clicks on another `Edit` button, this one will also be replaced with an `<input>`, and the previous `<input>` should disappear and show an `Edit` button again.

In short, only one field can be in edit mode at a time.

This is my initial `state`:

```
state = {
    editnameEnable: false,
    editemailEnable: false,
    editaddressEnable: false,
    edittelephone_noEnable: false,
}
```

This is my `edit()` method:

```
edit = value => {
    var address_element = ['name','address','email','telephone_no']; 
    address_element = address_element.filter(element => element !== value); 
    address_element.map( val => this.setState({[`edit${val}Enable`]: false}));

    this.setState({[`edit${value}Enable`]: true}, ()=>{
        console.log(this.state);
    });
}
```

This is part of the JSX inside my `render` method:

```
<td>{
    this.state[`edit${this.props.item}Enable`] ? ( <input type="text"/> ) : (
        <span
            className="edit"
            onClick={ () => this.edit(this.props.item) }>Edit</span>
    )
}</td>
```

The issue is that when I click on an `Edit` button, the `<input>` appears, but when I click another `Edit` button, the previous `<input>` does not disappear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about using a single `editableField` property that is initially set to `null`?

Then, when you click on an `Edit` button, you set `editableField` to the name of that field, and inside `render` you check, for each field, whether `editableField` matches its name or not to render an `Edit` button or an input field.

Something like this:

```js
class FieldCell extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  
  focusField = (element) => element && element.focus();
  
  render() {
    const editElement = this.props.isEditable ? (
      <input type="text" ref={ this.focusField }/>
    ) : (
      <button onClick={ () => this.props.onEdit() }>EDIT</button>
    );
    
    return (<td className="textLeft">{ editElement }</td>);
  }
}

class UserData extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      editableField: null,
    };
  }
  
  render() {
    const editableField = this.state.editableField;
    
    const rows = ['Name', 'Address', 'Telephone No.', 'E-Mail'].map((field) => {
      const isEditable = field === editableField;
      
      return (
        <tr key={ field }>
          <td>{ field }</td>
          <FieldCell isEditable={ isEditable } onEdit={ () => this.setState({ editableField: field })}></FieldCell>
        </tr>
      );
    });

    return (<table>{ rows }</table>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<UserData />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 13px;
}

table {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.textLeft {
  text-align: left;
  user-select: none;
}

button,
input {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 13px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
}

button:hover,
button:focus,
input:hover,
input:focus {
  border-color: blue;
  color: blue;
}

button {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Danziger. Your solution is working as per my requirement. But your are `returning` almost the whole table. But I would like to return only the affected `td`. I think state is creating the issue. Only `true` state is displaying output but `false` state is not working here. Thanks.

Comment: @abuabu When you say _But I would like to return only the affected `td`_ do you mean that you have another component that renders just a single `td` and then another component that renders the `table`?

Comment: @abuabu Hey, sorry, I was on holidays. I have updated the code to use a separated component and props to render it as editable or not and to send events to the parent component when entering edit mode.