# React. Editeble table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Immediately apologize for my English.

In the table opposite each row there should be an “edit” button, when you click on it, all cells in the row become editable, and instead of the “edit” button, the “save” button appears.
I spent a lot of time and just can't figure it out.

I need to release without react tables, react grid etc.

My table:

```
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {props.items.map(item => (
                    <tr key={item.id}>
                        <td>{item.data.name}</td>
                        <td>{item.data.surname}</td>
                        <td>{item.data.age}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button onClick>Edit</button> //need to improve this button

                            <button onClick={() => removeID(user.id)}>Delete</button>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React.js - Conditionally rendering and editable input with JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51348505/react-js-conditionally-rendering-and-editable-input-with-jsx). The only difference I see is that in your case there's more than 1 input, but the solution would still be similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest is you save a state for specifying if the current table is on edit mode or not. This could be as simple as setting the initial state as `{ editMode: false }` and you would create an onClick handler on your button that would set the state of `editMode` to `true`, (I can't tell from the example if you are going to use hooks or not so simply look into how you would change the said state).

Now, having that state, you could do this `<button onClick={this.toggleEditMode}>{ editMode ? "Save" : "Edit" }</button>` , if `editMode` is `true`, then show `Save` else `Edit`

For the cells to be editable, that's another problem entirely but the approach I would suggest is to utilize the `editMode` state, change the value of the tds with inputs with the same approach above then you have to attach `onChange` handlers that would update the `items` props. Just a matter of figuring out which item to update in which that key prop will help you do so.